# How to create a Grid like pattern as shown below using adobe illustrator tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

Grid like pattern needs to created for logo background Same like the image shown below [image]

Comment: What part of the process are you struggling with? Drawing Squares, aligning them, applying the colour, adding the title drop shadows... Please clarify your question so that we can better help you.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a rectangle

Object > path > Split Into Grid

Live Paint Bucket tool to add colors to squares.

Draw rounded rectangle on top

Select all

Object > Clipping Mask > Make